# Laravel consulta "multiple" where

Tags: laravel, sql

Estimados con esta función obtengo una lista de grupos a los que pertenece un usuario:

```
$idgrupos=User::findOrFail(Auth()->user()->id)->grupospertenece
                ->pluck('id');
```

de la que obtengo por ejemplo:

[1,2,5]

Este dato puede tener más o menos grupos.

Entonces quisiera consultar

```
$join = DB::table('clasificaciones')->join('tablauno', 'clasificaciones.id', '=', 'tablauno.idcategoria')
    ->select('clasificaciones.*', 'tablauno.*')
    ->where('tablauno.idgrupo', ??? )
    ->where("tablauno.estado",'VISIBLE')
    ->get();
```

Mi pregunta es:
¿Cómo hacer para que me entregue los datos donde tablauno.idgrupo sea alguno de los valores de $idgrupos que por ejemplo pueden ser para este ejemplo 1 o 2 o 5?.

Es decir obtener todos los datos que pertenezcan a los grupos 1,2 o 5

Comment: Usa whereIn en vez de where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener los elementos que pertenecen a una lista o a un numero dado de valores, puedes hacerlo haciendo uso de `wherein` que es la forma de query builder para hacer una sentencia del tipo `WHERE column IN (list)`

```
->whereIn("idgrupo",[1,2,5])
```

Puedes leer mas sobre esto en [Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries)

Comment: Cierto, mi error, modifico

Comment: Exacto, yo soy mas fan de usar whereIn cuando debo hacer una consulta con listas, sin embargo tampoco esta de mas que se conozcan ambos metodos

Comment: Tienes razon, no considere lo del loop, lo modifico

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias por la observacion.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Me funciono perfecto